# Android save JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I have problems saving my JSONArray , which i need for my game.
I have 2 Methods :

```
public void saveArr(Context c,JSONArray arr,String name){
    String fileName = name+"Arr.json";
    String data = "";
    if (arr != null) {

        /*
        Convert JSONArray to String
         */
        data = arr.toString();
       /*
       TODO PROBLEM data not compatible with JSONArray
        */
    }
    FileOutputStream fos;

    try {


        fos = c.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(data.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and

```
 public JSONArray getArrJSON(Context c,String name){
    StringBuilder sb =null;
    JSONObject obj=null ;
    JSONArray arr = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = c.openFileInput(name+"Arr.json");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        //Here i get an Exception JSONException
        obj= new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        arr = deck.getJSONArray("arr");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

The JSONArray looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "pictures":[
       {
         "key":"value"
       }
  ],
  "name":"name",
  "id":"id"
 },
 {
  "pictures":[
        {
          "key":"value"
        }
  ],
  "name":"name",
  "id":"id"
 }
]
```

I get an Exception, which i cant post, since my json file is to long...
But is is a JSONException at this line :

```
`obj= new JSONObject(sb.toString());`
```

in the method `getArrJSON`

I dont know where my mistake begins.But i think that an error ist that :

```
 arr = deck.getJSONArray("arr");
```

But like i said before the exception is thrown in the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
obj= new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

try

```
arr = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
```

The string that you write to disk in the first method represents a JSONArray and not a JSONObject.

It's important to know the difference between a JSONObject and a JSONArray. A JSONArray (usually) contains JSONObjects, and a string representation of a JSONArray always start with a '['.

Comment: ok wow, looks like that worked,i followed a tutorial and they said, this is not possible :D thank you